# Using a user inputted formula in an Excel VBA function?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Very new to excel VBA coding. I am currently having an issue as I am trying to take a function that is entered by the user (say for example "x^2+2y^2+4". I have a function in my VBA program that needs to pull this formula from the spreadsheet so it can evaluate it at different values. The problem I am running into is when I use an inputbox for the formula, the data type is variant so the function cannot be evaluated since the data type is wrong. What can I do to pull a user-inputted formula and use it as my function within VBA?

Comment: Always helps to show the code you tried, and explain exactly what errors you're getting.

Comment: I agree with Tim, including your code might help others understand your problem. However, I suspect you misunderstand Variants.  If I write `Dim X As Variant` that just means that X can contain values of any type.  If I write `X = "abc"` then X contains a String.  If I write `X = 12.34` then X contains a Double.  You can use function `VarType` to check the user has entered a String.  You can use function `CStr` to convert a Variant to a String so it can be passed to a function that expects a String.

Answer (score 1):

The Evaluate() function is what you need:

```
Sub CalcFunc()
    Dim func As String, xValue, yValue, newFunc As String

    Const DEFAULT_FUNC = "x^2+2*y^2+4"
    func = "=" & InputBox("Enter function:", , DEFAULT_FUNC)
    xValue = InputBox("XValue:")
    yValue = InputBox("YValue:")
    newFunc = Replace(Replace(func, "x", xValue), "y", yValue)

    MsgBox "Function: " & func & vbCrLf & "X: " & xValue & vbCrLf & "Y: " & yValue & vbCrLf & "Answer: " & Application.Evaluate(newFunc)
End Sub
```